# Node.js: Asynchronous non-blocking control flow violated

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

One of my routes handles incoming HTTP-POST requests to create new book entries in a database (MEAN environment with Mongoose). The main handler employs an async waterfall for a series of actions, like such:

```
async.waterfall([
            {...},

            //extract book-hashtags from single string
            function(input, callback){
                hashtags.extractHashtags(req.body.hashtags, function(err, tagresult){
                    if(tagresult){
                        callback(null, tagresult, input); 
                    }
                });
            },

            //save hashtag-result-array to database
            function(callback){
                callback(null);
                [...]
            }

        ], function (err, result) {
            //...
        });
```

My extractHashtags function looks like this:

```
exports.extractHashtags = function(inputString, cb){
    async.series([
        //remove special characters
        function(callback){
            //...
            callback(null, results);
        },
        //remove all whitespaces
        function(callback){
            //...
            callback(null, results);
        },
        //extract hashtag-substrings
        function(callback){
            //...
            callback(null, results);
        }
    ],
    // final callback
    function(err, hashtagarray){
        //finally done, NOW return FINAL result
        cb(null, hashtagarray); 
    });
};
```

My problem: the code in the main handler (waterfall-code) does not wait for the final result from "extractHashtags" to return. At the same time, you could say, my extractHashtags function delivers a callback several times even though it hasn't fully finished it's work. Instead, I get a callback from each processing step of the series chain (in this case 3x callbacks). As a result, database writing occurs 3 times. I thought, by using async.series, I only send one callback once the entire processing is done. I got similar problems with other functions too and I think they all relate to the same issue: the control flow is not fully asynchronous proof.

1) Is there any way I can keep the current code and introduce minor changes to achieve the required (sequential) control flow without switching to blocking code?

2) If not, would Promises solve the problem (haven't been working with them yet, thus tried to avoid them as long as possible ;) )?

Comment: Yes, `async.js` is known for not working when callbacks are called multiple times. Promises would indeed solve the problem (and help you to not ignore errors), but fixing your `extractHashtags` function should be done in any case. Maybe you can post its actual code?

Comment: Yes, calling a callback multiple times does not seem desired. There will be an easy fix while still using `async`. Post some more code to help narrow possibilities.